# Applying CIFilter to NSImage error

Tags: objective-c, xcode, image, opengl, filter

I am trying to use CIFilter on NSImage. 
But I am getting `Thread 1: signal SIGABRT` error at `return NSApplicationMain(argc, (const char **)argv);` when trying to run it. And allot of console entries. Witch looks like this:

```
2012-07-30 10:07:29.696 OGL[962:303] -[NSConcreteData CGImage]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10180fde0
2012-07-30 10:07:29.696 OGL[962:303] An uncaught exception was raised
```

---

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I was creating NSBitmapImageRep wrong. It looked like this:

```
NSBitmapImageRep *bitmap = (NSBitmapImageRep*)[imageN TIFFRepresentation];
```

And had to look like this

```
NSData *imgData = [imageN TIFFRepresentation];
NSBitmapImageRep *bitmap = [NSBitmapImageRep imageRepWithData:imgData];
```